# perform an action maximum x times per hour

Tags: arduino-uno

is it possible to perform an action maximum x times per hour on the arduino?

I made a automatic water sprinkler that sprays when the humidity is lower than 50%. but if the sprayer performs this "spray" more than 4 times an hour the humidity wil be to high and wil rise to fast.so is there a way to restrict the amount of times an action is performed per hour,and then if the next hour comes the sprayer can perform his "sprays" 4 times before it stops again

sorry for bad english, this is not the language I speak (and type) mutch

Comment: Humidity rising too quickly indicates a lack of proper feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it's possible. It would be better if you had a real time clock module. Then you could use time-of-day.

You need to define your problem a little better. Would it be ok to run the sprinkler every 5 minutes, then not again for 40 minutes, for a total of 4 sprays in an hour, but clustered together? Do you want to prevent 4 sprays in a clock hour, or not go over an average of 4 sprays per hour?

Without a realtime clock module, I guess here's what I would do:

After a spray, record the time (in millis). Then in your loop, don't spray again for 15 minutes (15*1000*3600 milliseconds.)

The code would look something like this: (not real code, more like pseudocode)

```
const unsigned long fifteenMinutes = 15*1000*3600;
unsigned long nextSprayTime = 0;

loop()
{
  if (millis() >= nextSprayTime)
  {
    if (humidity < 50)
    {
      spray();
      nextSprayTime = millis() + fifteenMinutes;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: You said, in comments:

> i want it not to go over 4 sprays an hour,i have the ds1307 rtc
>   module. situation: ist an automatic egg incubator and the humidity
>   must be between 50% and 60%.i control the sprayer whit a dht11 sensor
>   an a servo connected to an spray bottle. if the humidity is below 50 %
>   the servo starts whit spraying.the servo keeps on spraying every
>   second until that 60% mark is reached and then shuts of.so the amount
>   of water in the box is way to much and so the humidity keeps on
>   climbing until the 100% mark whit is deadly for the eggs

Ok, that gives your readers a clearer picture.

You're dealing with a process control problem, not just a hardware or software problem.

When you spray water, it will likely take several minutes for the change in humidity to stabilize and be detected by your sensor.

Your current approach sounds wrong because you dump far too much water into the system, and don't give it time to reach a new equilibrium before adding more water.

You need to collect some data.

There is going to be a significant lag between putting a spray into the incubator and sensing the increase in humidity, and when the increase reaches it's max.

You need to measure that lag.

You also need to know how much a single spray increases the humidity.

You should probably **ALSO* figure out how many sprays at a time you can spray before water droplets form on the walls of your incubator and on your eggs, since I assume that is very bad and to be avoided at all costs. Thus I would add a moisture detector to your system (A small piece of cloth with electrodes on it at 2 locations a couple of CM apart, and a sensitive conductivity sensor that detects the change from insulator to weak conductor that takes place when the cloth becomes saturated with water.)

You should also figure out how fast the humidity in your incubator drops if you don't add any water, for a variety of different conditions. (Likely affected by current humidity, outside temp and outside relative humidity, so you probably want 2 humidity sensors, one inside and one outside the incubator, and to record all the variables and graph them.)

I would suggest writing a data collection program. You might want to run it with the serial cable connected to a PC constantly, or install an SD card and save your data there.

In all your tests, you probably want to wait a significant time (15 minutes? 1/2 hour? 1 hour?) for the incubator to reach equilibrium before beginning your test.

You want the conditions of your incubator to be as close to your real-world conditions as possible. You might want to put eggs (dummy eggs, grocery store eggs at room temp, or something like that) in the incubator during the test to allow for the amount of water they absorb. You want the outside temp to be as close to your real-world temp as possible. If the incubator will be exposed to direct sunlight, air vents, wind, etc, then you want those same conditions.

At each step in every test you should record the current time, the current outside temp and humidity, and the current incubator temp and humidity, and the time of each spray you trigger.

Add your condensation detector at the beginning, and any time it detects condensation you should sound an alarm, record the time that it trips, and abort the current test. If you get liquid condensation you've done something wrong and need to adjust.

Write a program for your computer that graphs all your data points over time. Every time you run a test (other than the very first test) graph all the data and look at it. Patterns will probably jump out at you.

**Test 1:**

Record the time and the current humidity. Add one spray of water, and then record the humidity for 15 minutes. Look for an increase in humidity and when it peaks. The time from adding a spray to the peak increase in humidity is what you want.

**Test 2:**

Then modify your program to log the spray-to-peak-humidity-increase time, and each time it detects the humidity starting to drop again, spray once more, log the current outside temp and humidity, the inside humidity and outside time of the spray, and repeat.

This will give you spray-to-peak-humitity lag times over a range of humidity values. Graph that data with starting relative humidity on the x axis and the lag time on the y axis and look at it. Is it a constant value? A straight line? Is it a geometric curve? Exponential? Come up with a curve that fits the data fairly well.

**Test 3:**

A test that uses an increasing number of sprays, looking for how many sprays you can do at once before you cause condensation.

Start with 2 sprays.

Look for the peak increase in humidity, and once the humidity starts to drop, increment your spray counter to 3, spray that many times, and repeat. When the condensation alarm trips, stop the test.

Note that the number of consecutive sprays you can do before the moisture alarm trips will probably change for different starting humidity levels. My guess is that the max number of sprays you can add without triggering condensation will be highest at your lowest humidity level, and as the humidity increases, you'll get condensation with less and less sprays.

**Test 4:**

Figure out how to measure the max number of sprays that trigger condensation when you start at less than your minimum humidity, at your minimum humidity, at halfway between min and max, and at max. (This experiment will take some thought since it's not easy to get to a given humidity level, and once you trigger condensation you'll have to stop, dry everything out, and start again.)

**Test 5:**

Get your incubator as close to the maximum acceptable humidity (60%) as you can at the beginning of the test, or even a little above. Simply record the humidity every minute until it drops to the lowest acceptable level (50%). Graph the data. That will show you how fast the humidity drops if you do nothing.

**Test 6:**

Repeat test 5 for the range of outside conditions you might find in your production environment. (If you're in a climate-controlled space, do you have summer and winter thermostat settings? Test for those upper and lower ranges. How much does your indoor humidity level vary?)

### Now what?

Now you have lots and lots of data.

More than likely you have an idea of how many sprays you can add at a time without triggering condensation over your humidity range. This should be fairly simple: (for example, at humidity < 50% to 52%, you can use 3 sprays.  AT 53-55%, 2 sprays. Above 55%, 1 spray.) You should also have a rough idea how much increase you'll get in humidity for a given number of sprays.

You have an idea of how fast the humidity drops if you don't add water.

You have an idea how long it takes for a spray set of sprays to cause a peak in the humidity level.

Write a program that strives to keep the incubator in the middle of your desired range. If 50% is your absolute minimum humidity level and 60% is your max, then trigger sprays at 52%, not 50%. Spray as many sprays as you can without causing condensation (or overshooting your max humidity), then lock out sprays for the time period you calculated as the time it takes for your sprays to cause the maximum increase in humidity.

If you've found that the max number of sprays you can do at a time is different for different humidity levels, use code that comes up with a number of sprays that stays below that limit. Also try to estimate how much increase in humidity you get per spray, and each time you trigger a series of sprays, stay below the number of sprays that reaches your max humidity.

If you've found that the conditions outside the incubator have a big effect on your system, adjust your code to compensate for those changing conditions.

You want a system that uses small adjustments over time to keep a system at near equilibrium. Big adjustments will likely cause wild variations in conditions that go outside of the acceptable range.

### Other considerations:

Do you need to open the incubator at regular intervals to check on the eggs or turn them, or do you have an egg turner? If you do need to open the incubator, you will need to figure out the effect this has on your temp and humidity levels for the range of outside conditions you face. You can probably build your system with a door sensor that detects you opening the door, the outside temp and humidity, and how long the door is open. Once you close the door, it would note the new inside temp and humidity and make an educated guess as to how much the humidity will drop after being open, and add water accordingly.

Comment: i want it not to go over 4 sprays an hour,i have the ds1307 rtc module.

situation: ist an automatic egg incubator and the humidity must be between 50% and 60%.i control the sprayer whit a dht11 sensor an a servo connected to an spray bottle. if the humidity is below 50 % the servo starts whit spraying.the servo keeps on spraying every second until that 60% mark is reached and then shuts of.so the amount of water in the box is way to much and so the humidity keeps on climbing until the 100% mark whit is deadly for the eggs

Comment: @BrianLaebens, see my edits.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer, but note that: 1) `fifteenMinutes = 15*1000*3600` triggers an integer overflow. You should add the suffix `UL` to at least one of the factors. 2) `if (millis() >= nextSprayTime)` will not work as expected when `millis()` rolls over, whereas `if (millis() - lastSprayTime >= fifteenMinutes)` is rollover-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You might be spraying faster than the sensor or the environment can respond, causing your humidity overshoot your goal. Try spraying way less often, experimenting with the interval until you understand more about the dynamics of the humidity.

My first guess would be to try once per minute and see whether that still overshoots or if it fails to maintain the humidity. That will tell you whether to increase the interval more or to decrease it. Writing the time and humidity readings to the terminal and plotting those may help you understand your system behavior better.